# querying an object from parse to show as a label using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to query an object from `Parse` and I had it working with the old swift code but I'm getting an error now.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"TapLimit")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (namelist: [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        for list in namelist {

            let output = list["Taps"] as! String
            self.TapLimit.text = output


            print(output)


        }

    }
```

The error is on the line that has `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`
and the error says

> "Cannot convert value of type ([AnyObject]!, NSError!) ->Void to
>   expected argument PFQueryArrayResultBlock?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From source of `Parce`:

> ```
> /*!
>  The `PFQuery` class defines a query that is used to query for <PFObject>s.
>  */
> @interface PFQuery PF_GENERIC(PFGenericObject : PFObject *) : NSObject<NSCopying>
>
> ///--------------------------------------
> /// @name Blocks
> ///--------------------------------------
>
> typedef void (^PFQueryArrayResultBlock)(NSArray PF_GENERIC(PFGenericObject) * __nullable objects, NSError * __nullable error);
> ```

it looks like your first array `namelist` in this line `(namelist: [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!)` should be array of `PFObject` type. Try to change `[AnyObject]` to `[PFObject]` diractly

Comment: @RedLineTom Try to use like this `(namelist: [PFObject]?, error : NSError?)` without unwrapping